# Ask a token to an API with ajax

Tags: ajax, request, token

I used postman to have a token from an web API. It worked and I found the code to ask with ajax and with the token, but I would like to ask a token just with ajax. I tried this :

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://mysite.pot/projects.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        data: {
            "client_id": "abc",
            "client_secret": "xyz",
            "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("yeah !!")
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Try again")
        }
    })
```

with postman we use a callback url, auth url and access token url but I don't know where use them with ajax...

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the web and it's work for me.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "url",
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
      headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"url" },
      crossDomain:true,
      cache : true, 
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
          client_id:  "clien_id",
          client_secret:  "client_secret",
          redirect_uri: "url call_back",
      },

      success: function (data) {
          $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, " "));;
      },
      error: function (e) {
          $('#response').html(e.responseText);
      }
  });
```